# Plotting Box plots from Multiple Responses from Multiple Columns

Tags: r, statistics, boxplot

Helloo everyone..
I am stack in plotting a boxplot using r. My dataset has Columns of Crops, Response and Technology type. Within columns, there are multiple responses: Yes, No, and Not sure. Now, I would like to plot boxplots from Crops column of Yes and No response, while leaving out Not sure. How should I do this in r?

Comment: It would be nice if you provide sample data with your question. You should also do a websearch first so that you might find at least part of a solution until you get stuck. These things make it easier to find an appropriate solution. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any sample data I can't answer your question based on your data.
However, I suppose something like this might solve your problem:

```
plot_data <- your_data[!your_data$Response %in% "Not sure",]
boxplot(Crops~Response, data=plot_data)
```

You'll have to index your data first in order to remove all "Not sure" cases.
Then you create a boxplot, in this example via R's base plotting system.
Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to base R you can also use dplyr and ggplot, something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

myplot <- your_data %>% filter(Crops != "Not sure") %>%
        ggplot(aes(x=Crops, y=Response)) +
        geom_boxplot()
plot(myplot)
```